# Download a file from a link on a WPF Browser Application application

Tags: wpf

How do I download a file from a link on a 
WPF Browser Application application, I am using 
the method NavigationService.Navigate(http://www.google.com/docs/Arquivo.xlsx ") Works for download window opens but after that 
download was completed or canceled I can not 
but enter navigate the pages using method 
NavigationService.Navigate, I noticed that the 
Content property of NavigationService is null 
when I navigate to a file path, someone 
know what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

I don't actually understand what are your goals.

If you need to download file it's better to use WebRequest rather than NavigationService:

```
        var request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.farmanager.com/files/Far20b1777.x86.20110108.msi");
        using (var stream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                var fileContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
```